# Unity Android Marshmallow .obb File Access Permission Error on Some Devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, unity-game-engine

I have a problem on some Android 6.0 devices. My Unity application about 200 MB and thats why I have `.obb` file. After installing the game to Google Play, Samsung Android 6.0 devices gives error about accessing the assets.

If i allow the storage permission manually from **Settings -> App Management -> Permissions**, the problem disappears. This is happening only some Android 6.0 devices. I have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Can you help me about this please?

Comment: did you read about how to handle permissions in 6.0 and up? https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I know about it but it is confusing that some devices gives the error but some don't give and work.

Answer (score 0):

Now is different in android marsmallow. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=es)

Now with android 6.0 you must ask for permissions when you go to use this permission, so you need declare in android manifest, and also you must request the permissions you need in the class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will research how can i do it in Unity. It is interesting that only some Android M devices gives this error and some of them works perfectly...

Comment: hahahaha, yes is Android, maybe in unity wiki you can find something about this.